# Which group should own /var/www/html?

Tags: permissions

I have a *CentOS 7* VM setup on my *Windows 7* host.

I have installed `vsftpd` and `ftp` and can now successfully connect from the host with FileZilla, but the user I log in as doesn't have permissions to write to `/var/www/html` and so I cannot upload files there. `/var/www/html` is owned by `user:root` and `group:root`.

I know I shouldn't add my user to the root group. Instead, should I change the group which owns the directory to another (e.g. make one like `www-admins`) and add my user to that group? I am fairly new to linux and so am wary about changing permissions on directories...

Answer (score 2):

Normally the webserver user owns that directory. If you're using apache2 then usually its www-data user/group that owns them.

To check which user is running apache2 u can use:

```
sudo ps aux | grep apache[2]
```

Or if you dont use sudo, u can use:

```
su
ps aux | grep apache[2]
```

You may have 1 process that root runs, but the rest should be the apache2 user.

To change the owner and group of the files u can use:

```
sudo chown -R apache2_user:apache2_user
```

Where apache2_user is the user that you got from the `ps` command above. Then you can add yourself to that group to gain access. Note that if you dont use sudo, u can use `su` to gain root so u can chown the directory and files. eg.

```
su
chown -R apache2_user:apache2_user
```

Comment: The folders I am interested in are owned by apache (user and group). I've added my user to the apache group but that is not enough - only the apache user has write permissions - the group only has read and execute. Should I add write permissions to those folders for the apache group too or this that a bad idea?

Comment: The apache group should have read and execute as well as other. There are some files that should not have read execute for other, but perhaps you can find those and mark them for later permission changes. So if you are willing to change permissions try this: `sudo chmod -R go+rx /var/www/html/`

Comment: `ps aux` relies on Apache running already. You can also search the conf file: `egrep -i '^user|^group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (from @quanta http://serverfault.com/a/416239/15882)